# What's the difference between "uzantnomo", "uzulnomo", and "salutnomo"?

Tags: word-meaning

Are the words *uzantnomo*, *uzulnomo*, and *salutnomo* basically just variations of the same thing?

In English there are the words *username*, *user ID*, *login name*, *login ID*, etc, which all basically mean the same thing, but could be used differently based on the situation.  You might sign in with your *login ID*, for example, but your *username* is displayed on your profile.

Is this the case with these three Esperanto words?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They all mean pretty much the same thing. It's a case of the Esperanto terms for this not stabilizing yet.